# Color change on SVG in dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm trying to change color of a SVG image of a cupcakes topping and bottom.

I've made a code snippet showing it working on buttons, adding and removing a class to the button on click. However I need it to work on the dropdown menu when you choose and option.

I've added the code to a JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bz7e3x4h/

I know my JS script only adds the class to buttons but when I try to add it to an option on the dropdown instead it won't work.

This is my JS script:

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons button");
var cat = document.getElementsByClassName("cat")[0];

for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", manageCatClasses);
}

function manageCatClasses(){
    if(this.getAttribute("data-add")) {
        cat.classList.add(this.getAttribute("data-add"));
    }
    if(this.getAttribute("data-remove")) {
        cat.classList.remove(this.getAttribute("data-remove"));
    }  
}
```

This is my CSS file:

```css
.blue-top .top-color{
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    fill: #1100ff
}

.brown-top .top-color{
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    fill: #8B4513
}

.brown-bottom .bottom-color{
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    fill: #8B4513
}
```

The index page:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">

    <title>Cupcake</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>SVG color change</h2>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button data-add="blue-top">Blueberry top</button>
        <button data-add="brown-bottom">Chocolate bottom</button>

    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Toppings</label>
        <select class="form-control dropbtn btn-danger btn-style mb-2 btn-block" name="toppingname"
                id="topping">
           <option data-add="brown-top">Chocolate</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Blueberry</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Rasberry</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Crispy</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Strawberry</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Rum/Raisin</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Orange</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Lemon</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Blue cheese</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <svg  class="cat" width="640" height="480" version="1.1" id="Lag_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 2834.6 2834.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2834.6 2834.6;" xml:space="preserve">

<path id="XMLID_301_" class="top-color" d="M1757.5,449.5c82.1,58.7,135.2,149.8,145.7,250.2c4.9,47.2,7.5,91.6,8.1,117.2
   c0.7,28.9,13.3,37.1,41.2,35.5c180.3-10.8,342,79.7,412.9,241.8c64.4,147.2,46.4,289.7-52.8,418.9c-92.1,119.9-219.5,160-364.4,160
   c-188.8,0-377.5,0-566.3,0c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c-186.5,0-372.9,0.8-559.4-0.3c-85.7-0.5-169.7-10.1-244.9-58.4
   c-129.7-83.2-196.1-200.5-191.5-354.8c5.9-194,141.1-327.3,312.2-375.1c22.8-6.4,47.9-5,72-6.4c35.4-2.1,43-8.9,30.8-42.3
   c-3.6-9.9-6.3-23.2-8.3-38.6C774.9,653.6,847.3,514.2,974,445.1l46.1-25.1c51.8-28.2,109.8-43,168.7-43H1543
   c73.5,0,145.1,23,204.9,65.7L1757.5,449.5z M968.3,1260.9c40.4-24.4,79.2-45.7,115.1-71.1c7.4-5.2,10.4-30.6,4.5-37.3
   c-9.3-10.8-31.4-22.7-41.5-18.5c-36.6,15.4-71.6,35.7-104.6,58c-8.5,5.8-12.9,27.8-9.1,38.7C936.8,1242,953.2,1248.9,968.3,1260.9z
    M727.7,1406.8c-3.1-5.1-7.5-17.6-16.1-25.4c-24.6-22.1-50.6-42.8-76.7-63.2c-16.9-13.2-34-11.9-49.3,3.6
   c-16.2,16.5-13.7,34,1.6,48.3c27.5,25.7,55.2,51.5,85.3,73.8C696.4,1461.6,727.7,1443.1,727.7,1406.8z M1690.8,1416.7
   c-7.7-9.4-14.2-24.5-24.5-28c-12-4-31.1-2.7-40.6,4.7c-27.7,21.8-54.2,46-76.8,72.9c-8,9.6-9.4,33.3-3.1,44.5
   c10,17.8,30.3,25.3,49.4,8.1c28-25.1,55.4-50.8,82.4-77.1C1683,1436.7,1685,1428.1,1690.8,1416.7z M2022,1153.1
   c-1.4-3.5-2.1-13.9-7.5-17.6c-34.6-24.2-69.2-49-106.3-68.8c-8.2-4.3-31.7,7.3-38.8,17.9c-5.8,8.6-2.5,33,5.5,39.3
   c31.3,24.8,65.1,47,100,66.5C1996.4,1202.4,2022.4,1182.3,2022,1153.1z M944.1,1484.8c24.1-0.1,47-22.2,46.9-45.3
   c0-23.7-26-49.5-48.9-48.7c-22.8,0.8-44.8,25-44,48.3C899,1464.8,919.2,1484.9,944.1,1484.8z M648.1,1183.5
   c23.8-0.7,47.3-24.1,46.6-46.3c-0.7-21.4-26.3-45.8-48.3-46c-24.4-0.3-48.7,25-47.2,49.2C600.5,1164.8,622.7,1184.3,648.1,1183.5z
    M1159.5,875.7c0.3-24.1-20.8-47.2-43.9-48.1c-23-0.9-45.5,21.1-46.5,45.6c-1.1,26.3,20.9,50.4,45.5,49.8
   C1138.2,922.4,1159.1,900.4,1159.5,875.7z M1326.2,1305.8c-24.5,0.7-44.4,21.9-44.3,47.2c0.1,22.8,23.5,47.3,45.1,47.3
   c21.6-0.1,49.7-27.6,49.8-48.8C1377,1328.5,1351,1305,1326.2,1305.8z M2097.4,1398.3c1.4-25.5-17.3-46.6-42.9-48.2
   c-23.5-1.4-48.2,19.8-49.9,42.8c-1.6,22.3,20.7,46.5,44.4,48.1C2073.8,1442.8,2096,1423.1,2097.4,1398.3z M1714.5,926.5
   c0.6-24.7-19.5-47.8-42.8-49.2c-23.7-1.4-49.5,23.1-49.4,46.9c0.1,21.5,24.7,47.2,45.8,48C1690.3,973,1713.9,949.8,1714.5,926.5z"/>

<path id="XMLID_300_" class="bottom-color" d="M1372,2570.5c-197.9,0-395.8-0.8-593.7,0.7c-35.9,0.3-55.3-10.5-63.5-46.3
   c-20.5-89.6-43.2-178.7-64.8-268.1c-37.7-156.4-75.1-312.9-113.1-469.3c-7.3-30.1,10.2-73.1,40.1-80.8c11.4-2.9,29.5,7.2,40,16.5
   c28.1,24.6,36.3,26,60.9-2c19.8-22.5,37.2-21,58.1-0.8c31.5,30.5,36.2,30,65.9-2c17.7-19.1,33.7-19.9,52.5-0.9
   c32.9,33.1,37.6,33.6,68.7,0.4c21.5-23,37.9-19.9,56.6,2.4c23.9,28.7,34.4,28.7,61,3.1c30-28.8,36-29,63.4,1.5
   c19.1,21.3,36.3,25,56.8,0.8c25.6-30.2,37.6-31.3,63.6-2.3c23.8,26.6,41.6,21.9,61.4-3c17.2-21.5,34.8-21.2,55.1-1.4
   c32.9,32.1,37.2,31.6,68.9-1.5c18.5-19.3,34.6-17.9,52.6,0.7c30.8,31.9,36.3,32.6,65.9,1.1c22.3-23.7,39.4-21.8,59.3,1.9
   c23,27.5,33.5,27,60.5,0.7c26.2-25.6,35.9-25.4,62,1.6c25.3,26.1,35.7,26.2,60.2-2.2c19.1-22.1,36.2-22.4,57.6-2.1
   c33.1,31.3,34,30.4,67.6-3.2c17.2-17.2,32.8-16.3,50.4,0.9c34.8,34,38.9,33.9,71.2-0.9c20.7-22.4,37.3-17.5,53.5,4.1
   c17.4,23.2,35.5,31.3,59.2,6.5c12.3-12.8,22.3-34.5,48-19.9c27.2,15.5,45.4,46.4,39.1,73.5c-6.5,27.9-14.9,55.4-21.7,83.3
   c-47.4,194.3-94.7,388.6-141.7,583c-5.9,24.6-9.8,49.7-15.2,74.3c-7.3,33.2-24.6,49.8-62.4,49.5c-201.3-1.6-402.7-0.8-604.1-0.8
   C1372,2570,1372,2570.2,1372,2570.5z"/>
</svg>

<script src="js/main.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I also wanted to know how to change color of svg with css. For different colors I am using different icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go you can use the `onchange` on the `HTML` parameter or you can do the same in `JavaScript` as well use an `id` or something. You also need to change a little bit of the function structure. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Update:

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons button");
var cat = document.getElementsByClassName("cat")[0];
var topping = document.getElementById('topping');

for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", manageCatClasses);
}

topping.addEventListener("change", manageCatClasses);

async function manageCatClasses(){
    var element = this;

    try {
      element = await this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    } catch(e) {
      // do nothing
    }
    
    var dataAdd = element.getAttribute("data-add");
    if(dataAdd)
        cat.classList.add(dataAdd);
        
    var dataRemove = element.getAttribute("data-remove");
    if(dataRemove) {
        cat.classList.remove(dataRemove);
    }
}
```

```css
:root{
    --primary-color: #f1324d;
    --secondary-color: #f9e6b2 ;
    --third-color: #FCB0B3 ;
    --text-color: #00000;
}

body{
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.blue-top .top-color{
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    fill: #1100ff
}

.brown-top .top-color{
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    fill: #8B4513
}

.brown-bottom .bottom-color{
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    fill: #8B4513
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">

    <title>Cupcake</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>SVG color change</h2>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button data-add="blue-top">Blueberry top</button>
        <button data-add="brown-bottom">Chocolate bottom</button>
    
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Toppings</label>
        <select onchange="manageCatClasses()" class="form-control dropbtn btn-danger btn-style mb-2 btn-block" name="toppingname"
                id="topping">
           <option data-add="brown-top">Chocolate</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Blueberry</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Rasberry</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Crispy</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Strawberry</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Rum/Raisin</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Orange</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Lemon</option>
           <option data-add="blue-top">Blue cheese</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <svg  class="cat" width="640" height="480" version="1.1" id="Lag_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 2834.6 2834.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2834.6 2834.6;" xml:space="preserve">

<path id="XMLID_301_" class="top-color" d="M1757.5,449.5c82.1,58.7,135.2,149.8,145.7,250.2c4.9,47.2,7.5,91.6,8.1,117.2
   c0.7,28.9,13.3,37.1,41.2,35.5c180.3-10.8,342,79.7,412.9,241.8c64.4,147.2,46.4,289.7-52.8,418.9c-92.1,119.9-219.5,160-364.4,160
   c-188.8,0-377.5,0-566.3,0c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c-186.5,0-372.9,0.8-559.4-0.3c-85.7-0.5-169.7-10.1-244.9-58.4
   c-129.7-83.2-196.1-200.5-191.5-354.8c5.9-194,141.1-327.3,312.2-375.1c22.8-6.4,47.9-5,72-6.4c35.4-2.1,43-8.9,30.8-42.3
   c-3.6-9.9-6.3-23.2-8.3-38.6C774.9,653.6,847.3,514.2,974,445.1l46.1-25.1c51.8-28.2,109.8-43,168.7-43H1543
   c73.5,0,145.1,23,204.9,65.7L1757.5,449.5z M968.3,1260.9c40.4-24.4,79.2-45.7,115.1-71.1c7.4-5.2,10.4-30.6,4.5-37.3
   c-9.3-10.8-31.4-22.7-41.5-18.5c-36.6,15.4-71.6,35.7-104.6,58c-8.5,5.8-12.9,27.8-9.1,38.7C936.8,1242,953.2,1248.9,968.3,1260.9z
    M727.7,1406.8c-3.1-5.1-7.5-17.6-16.1-25.4c-24.6-22.1-50.6-42.8-76.7-63.2c-16.9-13.2-34-11.9-49.3,3.6
   c-16.2,16.5-13.7,34,1.6,48.3c27.5,25.7,55.2,51.5,85.3,73.8C696.4,1461.6,727.7,1443.1,727.7,1406.8z M1690.8,1416.7
   c-7.7-9.4-14.2-24.5-24.5-28c-12-4-31.1-2.7-40.6,4.7c-27.7,21.8-54.2,46-76.8,72.9c-8,9.6-9.4,33.3-3.1,44.5
   c10,17.8,30.3,25.3,49.4,8.1c28-25.1,55.4-50.8,82.4-77.1C1683,1436.7,1685,1428.1,1690.8,1416.7z M2022,1153.1
   c-1.4-3.5-2.1-13.9-7.5-17.6c-34.6-24.2-69.2-49-106.3-68.8c-8.2-4.3-31.7,7.3-38.8,17.9c-5.8,8.6-2.5,33,5.5,39.3
   c31.3,24.8,65.1,47,100,66.5C1996.4,1202.4,2022.4,1182.3,2022,1153.1z M944.1,1484.8c24.1-0.1,47-22.2,46.9-45.3
   c0-23.7-26-49.5-48.9-48.7c-22.8,0.8-44.8,25-44,48.3C899,1464.8,919.2,1484.9,944.1,1484.8z M648.1,1183.5
   c23.8-0.7,47.3-24.1,46.6-46.3c-0.7-21.4-26.3-45.8-48.3-46c-24.4-0.3-48.7,25-47.2,49.2C600.5,1164.8,622.7,1184.3,648.1,1183.5z
    M1159.5,875.7c0.3-24.1-20.8-47.2-43.9-48.1c-23-0.9-45.5,21.1-46.5,45.6c-1.1,26.3,20.9,50.4,45.5,49.8
   C1138.2,922.4,1159.1,900.4,1159.5,875.7z M1326.2,1305.8c-24.5,0.7-44.4,21.9-44.3,47.2c0.1,22.8,23.5,47.3,45.1,47.3
   c21.6-0.1,49.7-27.6,49.8-48.8C1377,1328.5,1351,1305,1326.2,1305.8z M2097.4,1398.3c1.4-25.5-17.3-46.6-42.9-48.2
   c-23.5-1.4-48.2,19.8-49.9,42.8c-1.6,22.3,20.7,46.5,44.4,48.1C2073.8,1442.8,2096,1423.1,2097.4,1398.3z M1714.5,926.5
   c0.6-24.7-19.5-47.8-42.8-49.2c-23.7-1.4-49.5,23.1-49.4,46.9c0.1,21.5,24.7,47.2,45.8,48C1690.3,973,1713.9,949.8,1714.5,926.5z"/>
   
<path id="XMLID_300_" class="bottom-color" d="M1372,2570.5c-197.9,0-395.8-0.8-593.7,0.7c-35.9,0.3-55.3-10.5-63.5-46.3
   c-20.5-89.6-43.2-178.7-64.8-268.1c-37.7-156.4-75.1-312.9-113.1-469.3c-7.3-30.1,10.2-73.1,40.1-80.8c11.4-2.9,29.5,7.2,40,16.5
   c28.1,24.6,36.3,26,60.9-2c19.8-22.5,37.2-21,58.1-0.8c31.5,30.5,36.2,30,65.9-2c17.7-19.1,33.7-19.9,52.5-0.9
   c32.9,33.1,37.6,33.6,68.7,0.4c21.5-23,37.9-19.9,56.6,2.4c23.9,28.7,34.4,28.7,61,3.1c30-28.8,36-29,63.4,1.5
   c19.1,21.3,36.3,25,56.8,0.8c25.6-30.2,37.6-31.3,63.6-2.3c23.8,26.6,41.6,21.9,61.4-3c17.2-21.5,34.8-21.2,55.1-1.4
   c32.9,32.1,37.2,31.6,68.9-1.5c18.5-19.3,34.6-17.9,52.6,0.7c30.8,31.9,36.3,32.6,65.9,1.1c22.3-23.7,39.4-21.8,59.3,1.9
   c23,27.5,33.5,27,60.5,0.7c26.2-25.6,35.9-25.4,62,1.6c25.3,26.1,35.7,26.2,60.2-2.2c19.1-22.1,36.2-22.4,57.6-2.1
   c33.1,31.3,34,30.4,67.6-3.2c17.2-17.2,32.8-16.3,50.4,0.9c34.8,34,38.9,33.9,71.2-0.9c20.7-22.4,37.3-17.5,53.5,4.1
   c17.4,23.2,35.5,31.3,59.2,6.5c12.3-12.8,22.3-34.5,48-19.9c27.2,15.5,45.4,46.4,39.1,73.5c-6.5,27.9-14.9,55.4-21.7,83.3
   c-47.4,194.3-94.7,388.6-141.7,583c-5.9,24.6-9.8,49.7-15.2,74.3c-7.3,33.2-24.6,49.8-62.4,49.5c-201.3-1.6-402.7-0.8-604.1-0.8
   C1372,2570,1372,2570.2,1372,2570.5z"/>
</svg>

<script src="js/main.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When running the code it pops a error..
error {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 134,
  "colno": 13
}

Comment: Yes you should change the code you cannot use `this.getAttribute()` since `this` has different context when called from `onchange` it's pointing to a different `element`, I'm not going to do that for you but you should instead select the item you want changed and then do the do diligence don't use `this`

Comment: Tried something like this ```var dropdwn = document.querySelectorAll("option:checked");
var cat = document.getElementsByClassName("cat")[0];
var topping = document.getElementById('topping');

for(i = 0; i < dropdwn.length; i++){
    dropdwn[i].addEventListener("click", changeTopColor);
}

function changeTopColor(){
    console.log('called')
    if(topping == "Blueberry"){
        cat.classList.add("data-add");
    }
}
```
But pretty sure im getting in to something ive got no clue about. But thanks for trying :)

Comment: I fixed it for you 

Comment: Thanks alot! Really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('option:checked');
```

that `return` selected option, u can use `addEventListener` to listen whenever the option change.